# NVD3 charts with Django - web page not responding upon call

Tags: python, django, charts, nvd3.js

I have the following view in my django project;

```
def ChartView(request):

connection = SQLSeverConnection('MSSQLServerDataSource')

times = connection.getColumnData('DateTimeStamp', 'reqColumn', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2011-01-21 19:30:00.000')
string_times = []
for theTime in times:
    string_times.append(theTime.DateTimeStamp)

start = string_times[0]
end = string_times[-1]

start_time = int(time.mktime(start.timetuple()))
end_time = int(time.mktime(end.timetuple()))

xdata = range(start_time, end_time, 1)
xdata = map(lambda x: start_time + x * 1000000000, xdata)

ydata = connection.getColumnData('AIKE0G_1_MVAr', 'DunbarGen', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2011-01-21 19:30:00.000')

tooltip_date = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "Value was ", "y_end": " units"},
               "date_format": tooltip_date}

chartdata = {
    'x': xdata,
    'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie,
}

charttype = "lineWithFocusChart"
chartcontainer = 'linewithfocuschart_container' # container name
data = {
    'charttype': charttype,
    'chartdata': chartdata,
    'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': True,
        'x_axis_format': '%d %b %Y %H',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': True,
    }
}
```

## pdb.set_trace()

```
return render_to_response('chart_view.html', data)
```

There are no errors (that would lead to a 500 page) but when go to chart_view the page never loads.

The type of object that .getColumnData() returns is a pyodbc.row which I have successfully turned into an int (that I assume nvd3 interprets for a datetime)

Can anybody help? Is this a good way to use nvd3? If there is a better way then I'd be very thankful if you were to provide an example.

template;

```
{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
    {% include_chart_jscss %}
{# Jquery CDN : Needed when using jquery_on_ready=True #}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}
</head>
<body>
{% include_container chartcontainer 400 '100%' %}
 </body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your chart_view.html? also maybe there are also some errors in browser console?

Comment: there you go! at the foot of the original post

Comment: Template is good. Did you check browser console for errors?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the xdata should look? Also must you have a y-value for every x? I think the line xdata = range(start_time, end_time, 1) may be the problem

Comment: ydata and xdata must haev same length. My xdata looks like this:

    xdata = list(range(nb_element))
    xdata = [(date_from + x * 86400)*1000 for x in xdata]

So in the end I have list of dates day by day.

Comment: i managed to sort it (see answer) turns out you don't need equal numbers of x and y data - i thought you would too!

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working, thankfully. The issue was with my ydata. From the database query it was in the following format;

```
[(4.4, ), (4.8, ), (4.2, ), (4.0, ), (4.2, ), (4.8, ), (2.0, ), (2.4, ), (3.0, )]
```

It should have looked like this for nvd3;

```
[4.4, 4.8, 4.2, 4.0, 4.2, 4.8, 2.0, 2.4, 3.0]
```

To perform the conversion;

```
ydata_badForm = connection.getColumnData('<column>', '<table>', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2011-01-21 19:30:00.000')

ydata = map(lambda x: x[0], ydata_badForm)
```

This creates a new list called ydata where the tuple first element of ydata is written into each index.

From here the ydata was in the correct list format (not a list of tuples) and on refresh got some nice charts!